# Мне нужно на словах просто объяснить строчку из кода

Tags: python

```
a=input("Введите первое число: ")
s=input("Введите второе число: ")
d=input("Введите третье число: ")
x = [a,s,d]
g=sorted(x)[len(x) // 2]
print(g)
```

`g=sorted(x)[len(x) // 2]`
объяснить вот эту строку

Answer (score 2):

1. `sorted(x)` возвращает отсортированный список `x`
2. `len(x) // 2` возвращает индекс центрального элемента
3. `sorted(x)[len(x) // 2]` возвращает [медиану](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) списка

Answer (score 1):

Выбор медианы. Отсортировали массив и взяли средний элемент (а при чётной длине - правый из них).